# Nginx: Connection refused after removing port bindings from docker-compose file

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx

Basically, I am trying to get access to MariaDB on the website. I needed to run a docker container so that it looks as if its network requests originate from the instance on which it runs (AWS Ubuntu Instance). For that, I used `network_mode: "host"` within my docker-compose file for each container. Also, I had to comment out the port bindings since they are not compatible with host network mode. However, now I get:

**Connection refused error**. I believe I have to change something within the nginx config file which is project.conf, but I am not sure what.

This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        restart: always
        build: ./app
        #ports:
        #    - "8501:8501"
        env_file:
            - .env
        command: streamlit run Main.py
        network_mode: "host"

    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.9.3
        #ports:
        #    - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
            - db_conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "xxx"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: "xxx"
            MYSQL_USER: "xxx"
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: "xxx"
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "xxx"
        network_mode: "host"
    nginx:
        restart: always
        build: ./nginx
        #ports:
        #    - "80:80"
        depends_on:
            - app
            - mariadb

volumes:
    db_data:
    db_conf:
```

And, this is the project.conf file:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name helloworld-st-app;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app:8501/;
    }
    location ^~ /static {
        proxy_pass http://app:8501/static/;
    }
    location ^~ /healthz {
        proxy_pass http://app:8501/healthz;
    }
    location ^~ /vendor {
        proxy_pass http://app:8501/vendor;
    }
    location /stream {
        proxy_pass http://app:8501/stream;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }

}
```

I tried removing 8501 from the url, still nothing. Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not clear why you're disabling Docker networking here: outbound network connections will always look like they originate from the host, regardless of whether they originate from a container or a non-container process (other hosts have no way to tell whether Docker was involved or not).  If you remove the `network_mode: host` and put the `ports:` back, what's the problem you're trying to work around?

Comment: Hmm, I am actually trying to get access to Mariadb on the website. After running this command, `docker-compose up -d` it is successfully completed but when I check the website it says: **OperationalError: (1130, "172.18.0.2' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server")** where 172.18.0.2 is the app from docker compose file ip address.